# TCP Connection: Recreating a socket that has been closed

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ftp

I am writing a client-side FTP program, and so far, after a successful connection the server will run in extended passive mode. Using the port number returned from the `EPSV` command, I can create client-side sockets like this:

```
void create_data_channel() {
  if ((data_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Cannot create client socket for data connection :(");
    exit(1);
  }

  data_server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  
  data_server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  data_server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)ftp_server->h_addr);
  bzero(&(data_server_addr.sin_zero),8); 

  // Connect to the ftp server at given port for data connection
  if (connect(data_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&data_server_addr, 
    sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("Cannot connect to the ftp server for data connection :(");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Now, whenever I want to send a command involving the data channel (e.g. `LIST`), I can first open a new socket using the method above, and get/send whatever data I need from/to the ftp server. Then, I close the data connection using `close(data_sock)`.

This works well for the first `LIST` command. However, if I were to try to run two or more `LIST` command, the program fails with my error message "Cannot connect to the ftp server for data connection :(". Why is this so? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a FTP server does not accept multiple connections to the same dynamic port. Therefore the `PASV` or `EPSV` commands need to be done before each data transfer so that the server creates a new listen socket and returns its port number to the client.

Comment: I see! Thanks so much for this succinct explanation. Give me 2 more minutes - I can't accept this as an answer yet.

Comment: What you say is true for the *default* transfer settings (`STREAM` transfer mode with data sent as file `STRU`ctures) that requires EOF to be indictated by closing the data connection. But, when transferring data using record `STRU`ctures, or using `BLOCK` or `COMPRESSED` transfer mode, EOF is indicated by distinct records/blocks, thus allowing the data connection to be reused for multiple transfers without having to close it in between. But those are less common modes to use, so servers might not support them nowadays.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: while in theory there are different transfer modes I don't think that anything but stream is used in practice today and in my opinion most client implementations support only stream mode. Also, the question explicitly states that the OP is closing the data connection after transfer.